# Reset python interpreter

Tags: python, linux

In my linux machine . Somethings wrong with python shell

```
[user@localhost ~]$ python
python                    python3.5                 python3.5m-i686-config    python3-coverage
python2                   python3.5-config          python3.5m-x86_64-config  python3-mako-render
python2.7                 python3.5m                python3-chardetect        python3-pyinotify
python3                   python3.5m-config         python3-config
```

and when i type python3.5

```
[user@localhost ~]$ python3.5
Python 3.5.0 (default, Feb 14 2017, 17:59:59) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> ^[[A
```

it doesn't give any suggestions of histroy. Whats happended with it?
I want to make it working as like new one . How to reset it ?

Comment: Here's a good article on the subject: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Comment: Huh? Can you explain what's actually wrong? I'm not seeing anything obvious in what you posted except a vague reference to "history", but everything seems to be working correctly...

Comment: To get previous command . i pressed **up arrow** . but it gave me **^[[A** . This is odd .

Comment: Are you running a different version of Python now, or on a different machine?  What was "the new [old?] one"?  It sounds like you're expecting GNU Readline to handle keyboard input (history, completion, etc.).  That's usually done in your startup file.  Do you have the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable set?  If so, does it name a file?  What's in that file?

Comment: No i dont have **PYTHONSTARTUP** enviroment variable set ?

Comment: Then copy the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable (and the file it names) from the server or login where this does work.

Comment: will you please provide me that file . I am unable to find it . and also provide me steps in answer

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things could be happening here, and you haven't provided much information about your setup, so all I can do is guess.

The easiest answer in any situation like this is always the same:
undo whatever changes you made;
restore the configs that used to work.
If you don't have backups, compare what you have now to some other machine (or login) that does work.

Assuming you've tried all that...

Arrow keys, command-completion, and history are typically provided by [GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (but hardly always --- I gather Macs use something else, and I don't know if Windows can provide any of those features at all).

### Python configs

Since Python 3.4, history in interactive mode was [enabled by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#readline-configuration):

> #### 29.13.1. Readline configuration
>
> *Changed in version 3.4*:
>   Activation of `rlcompleter` and history was made automatic.

Make sure you haven't *disabled* that automatic history by aliasing Python to `python -S` or anything similar.

Before that, a script would be named in the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable, and that script would be executed by the interactive Python session before presenting the `>>>` prompt.
The [Python 3.3 `rlcompleter` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/rlcompleter.html#module-rlcompleter) gave an example:

```
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print("Module readline not available.")
else:
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

### GNU Readline configs

It's possible GNU Readline is not enabled or is set to something bizarre.
Like Python's, the [GNU Readline config file](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9) is named by an environment variable, in this case `INPUTRC`.
If that variable is not set, the default config file is `~/.inputrc` or, if that doesn't exist, `/etc/inputrc`.
(Different Unix-like distributions could have changed those defaults.)

The [Readline history bindable commands](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC15) you'd want to look for are `previous-history` and `next-history`.
But if those are wrong, you'd probably notice it in more than just Python.

### Other options

The only other likely culprit is your window manager.
I can't help there.
Window managers are more likely to <del>screw up</del> help with things like `Ctrl`, `Caps Lock`, and `Num Lock` than arrow keys, anyway.

Anything more in-depth than the above is *highly* unlikely to be the cause.
If you'd been fiddling with `xmodmap` or `loadkeys` (or any of the *many* other layers between a keystroke and its result inside a GUI terminal), you'd remember it.

Again, the easiest solution is to identify and undo the changes you made, even if that means creating a new login so you have a blank slate to compare.

Comment: Its saying **module readline not available**. Should i have to install it through **pip** ?

Comment: @deepak:  How would I know?  You still haven't provided basic info like what OS you're running, or what you were doing when Python suddenly stopped working.  Maybe you've got a custom Python installation --- who knows?  That said, [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/4/library/readline.html) is part of the standard library, so if you can't `import readline`, then you have much bigger problems than arrow keys.  (Or maybe your system, whatever it is, uses `libedit` instead?)  If you're convinced your distro has shipped an incomplete Standard Library (bloody unlikely), file a bug with them.

Comment: i am running fedora24 x64 workstation . And i tried to reinstall python from official site of python thats it . nothing else. since that time this error is occuring.